# I want to show footer only on last page using xhtml2pdf in django template

Tags: python, django, xhtml2pdf

if i delete lastpage keyword then it shows footer on all pages but when i add lastpage keyword then it doesnt showing any footer

```
 <style>       
            {% block style %}
               @page lastpage{ ///last page keword line
                    size: {{pagesize}};
                    margin: 1cm;
                    @frame footer {
                        -pdf-frame-content: footerContent; ///footer div
                        bottom: 1cm;
                        margin-left: 1cm;
                        margin-right: 1cm;
                        height: 140px;
                    }
                }
            {%endblock%}
        </style>

    <body>
                    <div id="footerContent">
                <div class="botom">
                        test data
                </div>  
                <div class="agree">
                    I/We certify that our xxx...
                </div>  
            </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Have same problem, i need to usee diferente page, but without break page manual.